# XML кодировка UTF-8 и windows-1251

Tags: php, кодировка

Файл формирующий XML в формате “windows-1251”, сам файл XML в формате UTF-8.

```
if (!file_exists('./upload/'.$x_name.'/message_'.$x_name.'.xml')) { 


    $dom = new domDocument("1.0", "UTF-8"); 
    $root = $dom->createElement("body");
    $dom->appendChild($root);

    $mess = $dom->createElement("mess", $ProfMees); 
    $mess->setAttribute("id", "1");
    $mess->setAttribute("read", "0"); 
    $mess->setAttribute("date", date("m.d.Y H:i:s")); 
    $root->appendChild($mess); 

    $dom->save('./upload/'.$x_name.'/message_'.$x_name.'.xml');

    return;
}else{

    $dom = simplexml_load_file('./upload/'.$x_name.'/message_'.$x_name.'.xml');

    $mess = $dom->addchild("mess", $ProfMees );

    $mess->addAttribute("id", "1"); 
    $mess->addAttribute("read", "0");
    $mess->addAttribute("date", date("m.d.Y H:i:s")); 

    $dom->asXML('./upload/'.$x_name.'/message_'.$x_name.'.xml'); 

    return;
}
```

При вводе Латиницы все хорошо. При вводе кириллицы выдает ошибку:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: ./upload/365/message_365.xml:2: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE2 0xEF 0xEB 0xFB in <b>C:\Apache22\htdocs\uraweb\profil_user_message.php</b> on line
```

Подскажите как обойти эти камни?

Comment: Откройте XML файл в редакторе и посмотрите его кодировку.

Comment: открыл Codelobster  1251  и Unix. фигасе. и как мне при динамическом  создании файлов  такого не допускать?

Comment: На дворе 3 квартал 2015 года. Ни кто уже не должен работать в кодировке Win-1251 по определению.

Comment: прошу прощение но почему?

Comment: Ваш случай как раз такой, почему не нужно использовать Win-1251. Использовали бы на сайте UTF-8 проблемы, думаю, не возникло бы. P.S. Если заголовок в файле такой `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>` и данные в файле в кодировке Win-1251, то `simplexml_load_file()` конвертирует их автоматически в UTF-8 на стороне php, а вот будет ли обратная конвертация при записи не подскажу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прекрасная манера задавать вопросы.

> "Иду в винный магазин, но когда поворачиваю налево, то всегда попадаю на помойку. Подскажите, как добраться до алкоголя?".

Читатель должен сам догадаться, откуда идет горемычный автор, где он сворачивает, и где вообще происходят описываемые события.

> "Создаю XML файл. При вводе кирилицы выдает ошибку".

Читатель должен сам догадаться, что вводит автор, куда, и что имеется в виду под словами "ввод" и "кирилица".

При этом пример приводится **не того кода, который выдаёт ошибку,** а того, который работает нормально.

Ну ок, займемся гаданием.

Если "вводимые" данные прописаны прямо в скрипте, сохранённом в кодировке 1251, то разумеется, они вызовут ошибку. Поскльку данные в кодировке 1251 являются некорректными данными с точки зрения кодировки UTF-8. Следовательно, эти данные сначала надо перекодировать, используя функцию `mb_convert_encoding()`

Comment: простите за маргариновый вопрос. и спс за помощь